# Getting Undefined subroutine utf8::SWASHGET called at ./MIME/Parser/Filer.pm line 365

Tags: perl, email, extract, mime, attachment

I'm trying to extract attachments from incoming emails and I'm using the following code related to MIME::Tools:

```
$parser = MIME::Parser->new();
$parser->output_dir("./tmp");
$message  = $parser->parse_data($msg); # $msg contains the email contents
```

when calling `$parser->parse_data($msg)`, the script fails with the following:

**Undefined subroutine utf8::SWASHGET called at ./MIME/Parser/Filer.pm line 364**

This happens to be the first instance of regex matching in the Filer.pm file, so I'm assuming it's something to do with the way to regex matching is performed. I put a regex match earlier just to see if it is indeed related to that and it failed on that exact spot with the same error.

Any help with regards to this? I have no problem retrieving the emails and their contents, but the attachments have been a pain.

My perl version is 5.8.9, MIME::Tools - 5.502, I'm not a root user and sadly have no access to root privileges (I'm getting around this by using

```
BEGIN { unshift @INC, "~email/mime"; }
```

at the top where /mime contains all the lib folders from the relevant CPAN modules, in this case MIME)

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: cross-post http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=974419

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the helpful perl monks chimed in, the problem was that the shebang I was using pointed to an older version of perl (apparently there are two perl versions on our work environment, located in completely different locations which I had not been aware of).

It's still slightly mysterious why the older version would behave in such a way but I guess a solution to this would seem to be to upgrade to a newer version (as pointed out in the other post).

Anyway I'm not quite sure how okay cross-posting is, so apologies if my topic felt redundant due to being posted in two places, my initial motivation was that I'd get sufficiently different responses.

Comment: Cross-posting is okay **as long as you link to the other versions**, which you neglected. See http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=909976 for the rationale.